# html pattern Vietnamese character set should not allow number

Tags: regex, html, pattern-matching

I have RegEx pattern for name field:

`[a-zA-Z'-ŠšŽžÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿþƒ]`

But it is allowing numbers. I want the same pattern which should not allow numbers.

Comment: It's because you have `'-`. Remove that.

Comment: yes. you are right

Comment: I'd go ahead and remove this question if you're finished. Recommending this because this question is not likely to help others, and is relatively low effort. Save your first question for another time, and good luck on your dev journey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'-Š
```

This range matches any charachers in the range of charcode 39 to 352. Char codes 48-57 are 0-9 respectively. If you update that range you should be good.

Char codes:

https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Personal favorite regex testing site:

https://regexr.com/